# How can i reset my Umbraco CMS admin password?

Tags: c#, umbraco

I am using Umbraco Starter Website, trying to login with credentials but cant login, i have gone through umbraco document but still cant do

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Nothing to do with programming?  I thought I was having a bad day, but it seems yours was worse Alejandro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1 :**

Open SQL Server Management Studio
Create a new query using the database for your `umbraco` project. Copy and paste the following SQL:

```
UPDATE umbracoUser SET userdisabled = 0, userLogin = 'admin', userPassword = 'default' WHERE id = 0
```

Run the query. This has now made sure the admin account is enabled and and set the password to `default`.

This won't work yet though as passwords are stored as hash values, so you need to edit a setting in the web.config file temporarily.

**Step 2 :**

In the web.config file, at the root of your web project, use `Ctrl+F` to find `UsersMembershipProvider`

The `passwordFormat` will be set to `Hashed`. You need to change it to `Clear` so that you can login. Save the `web.config` file.

**Step 3 :**

Go to the `umbraco` login page and login with the username of admin and the password of default.

Once you have logged in, you need to change the `passwordFormat` in the `web.config` again back to `Hashed` and press Save.

**Step 4**

Now you can change the password for the admin user to a different one and it will be saved in the database with a `hashed` value instead of `clear text`.

To make sure it is storing passwords in the `hashed` format, run this SQL query after you have changed the password.

```
SELECT userName, userPassword FROM umbracoUser WHERE id = 0
```

You should see the admin username and the hashed password.

Answer (score 6):

This solution works for Umbraco 8

Find an admin user in your database

Update their password to:

WRNIcp5OKxjowAwyBbdXJw==uHFH281pvI0UQJgRdJb95T9gPT1sVXBHKhYcoW5L8LI=

To log in, use their username and that hashed password up there is actually: MyUmbracoPassword1

I came up with this because I tried the answer above and received an error that

"Cannot use ASP.Net Identity with UmbracoMembersUserStore when the password format is not Hashed"

So if you don't want to use my HASH then install a blank umbraco of the same version and setup your admin user with a password and then grab whatever the hash is for your brand new user from the database and feed it back into the system you actually want to get in to.